# Jest react-native, expect constant to be a be a [Function BezierEasing]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I've got this constant in react native that just sets certain bezier easing

```
const easeInQuad = Easing.bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
```

and associated jest test

```
test("Animation/easeInQuad should return correct value", () => {
  expect(easeInQuad).toBe("[Function BezierEasing]");
});
```

it currently outputs the following

> Animation/easeInQuad should return correct value
>
> ```
> expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>
> Expected value to be:
>   "[Function BezierEasing]"
> Received:
>   [Function BezierEasing]
>
> Difference:
>
>   Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received function.
> ```

What do I need to pass to `expect` in order to match what is being output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Function.name` to check the name, e.g.

```
expect(easeInQuad.name).toBe("BezierEasing");
```

It is probably also worth checking if it is a function first:

```
expect(easeInQuad).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
```